# How do I query only a single item from a database using LINQ?

Tags: linq

I would like to get a LINQ-to-SQL query that returns only one item, not a collection of them?

For example, I have a list of products with a particular name.  There are no products with duplicate names in the database, so I want to be able to query and return just that instance of that product.

```
Products product = from p in _productContext.Products 
                   where p.name.Equals("BrownShoes") 
                   select p;
```

How do I do something like that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.single.aspx):

```
Product product = _productContext.Products
                                 .Single(p => p.Name == "BrownShoes");
```

or

```
Product product = _productContext.Products
                                 .Where(p => p.Name == "BrownShoes")
                                 .Single();
```

There's no query expression syntax for Single, so you have to call it as a normal extension method. At that point your query is simpler written entirely with dot notation, hence the form above. You *could* write it as:

```
Product product = (from p in _productContext.Products 
                   where p => p.Name == "BrownShoes"
                   select p).Single();
```

But that's got a lot more fluff. If there isn't exactly a single element in the result, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: I prefer `SingleOrDefault()` because then testing for non-existence is as simple as checking for `null`, rather than handling an exception.

Answer (score 8):

I recommend using `IQueryable.SingleOrDefault()`.  `IQueryable.SingleOrDefault()` and `IQueryable.Single()` will throw an exception if there is more than one record, but `IQueryable.Single()` will also throw one if there is **less** than one record.  This means that if you are searching for a single record and for whatever reason it doesn't exist, you have to handle an exception.

Much better is IQueryable.SingleOrDefault(), because you just check for null:

```
var employee = (from e in context.Employees
                where e.ID == employeeID
                select e).SingleOrDefault();

if (employee == null)
{
    // Cope with employee not found
}

// Do stuff with employee
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `.Single()` or `.SingleOrDefault()`:

```
Products product = (from p in _productContext.Products where p.name.Equals("BrownShoes") select p).Single();
```

`Single()` will throw an exception if there's not exactly 1 product there, `SingleOrDefault()` will return null if it doesn't exist, or throw an exception if there are multiple.

Answer (score 3):

```
Products product = (from p in _productContext.Products 
                    where p.name.Equals("BrownShoes") 
                    select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you will find a product. An exception will be thrown if no product is found:

```
Products product = _productContext.Products
                       .Single(p => p.name.Equals("BrownShoes"));
```

Or, if no product is found, product will be null:

```
Products product = _productContext.Products
                       .SingleOrDefault(p => p.name.Equals("BrownShoes"));
```